# How to prevent inaccurate segmentation of enclosed background regions in Watershed Algorithm?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I'm using the watershed algorithm to segment bright spots on a dark background. The code is provided below, along with some images it generates.

In the second image, I've marked with red crosses the areas of enclosed background which are segmented as 'cells' (they're not biological cells, just using the word) - this is incorrect, they're part of the background, just enclosed by 'cells'. I see that this creates a false minimum, any help on how to prevent this?

```
    % Improve contrast, binarize
RFP_adjust = imadjust(RFP_blur, stretchlim(RFP_blur, 0.001));
figure, imshow(RFP_adjust), title('Contrast adjust');
RFP_binarized = imbinarize(RFP_adjust);
RFP_perimeters = bwperim(RFP_binarized);
% figure, imshow(RFP_binarized), title('Otsu thresholding');

    %2B - SEGMENTATION BY WATERSHED METHOD
    % Discover putative cell centroids and process
RFP_maxs = imextendedmax(RFP_adjust,  3000);
RFP_maxs = imclose(RFP_maxs, strel('disk',5));
RFP_maxs = imfill(RFP_maxs, 'holes');
RFP_maxs = bwareaopen(RFP_maxs, 5);
RFP_max_overlay = imoverlay(RFP_adjust, RFP_perimeters | RFP_maxs, [1 .3 .3]);
figure, imshow(RFP_max_overlay), title('Maxima');

    % Obtain complement - maxima become low-points (required for watershed)
RFP_comp = imcomplement(RFP_adjust);
RFP_imposemin = imimposemin(RFP_comp, ~RFP_binarized | RFP_maxs);
figure, imshow(RFP_imposemin), title('Inverted Maxima');

    % Apply watershed
RFP_watershed = watershed(RFP_imposemin);
mask = im2bw(RFP_watershed, 1);
overlay3 = imoverlay(RFP_adjust, mask, [1 .3 .3]);
figure, imshow(overlay3), title('Segmented cells');

    % Segment
RFP_cc = bwconncomp(RFP_watershed);
RFP_label_matrix = labelmatrix(RFP_cc);
whos labeled;
RFP_label = label2rgb(RFP_label_matrix, @spring, 'c', 'shuffle');
figure, imshow(RFP_label), title('Cells segmented');
```

Image 0 - result for image titled 'Maxima' (i.e. adjusted original image with maxima and outlines overlaid).[image]

Image 1 - the result for image titled 'inverted maxima'
[image: Result for image titled 'Inverted Maxima']

Image 2 - the result for image titled 'Cells segmented'
[image]

Comment: Not having your original starting image to look at makes it tough, but is there some way initially that you can identify what pixels are defined as background? You can then apply this later as a mask to ignore those regions when performing the watershed operation.

Comment: @gnovice, original image added (Image 0). I've used the method outlined in this link, which says: 

"we need to modify our image so that the cell borders have the highest intensity and the background is clearly marked (we mark is as negative infinity). We achieve this by first finding the maxima which should approximately correspond to the cell nuclei and then we transform the image such that the background pixels and these maxima are the only local minima in the image:"

http://blog.pedro.si/2014/04/basic-cell-segmentation-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like what is done in [the example included for the `watershed` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html#examples): use the background mask to set those pixels to `Inf`, perform the watershed operation, then set the background pixels in the result to 0. I believe you could change the watershed section of your code like so to achieve this:

```
% Apply watershed
RFP_watershed = RFP_imposemin;             % Added
RFP_watershed(~RFP_binarized) = Inf;       % Added
RFP_watershed = watershed(RFP_watershed);  % Modified
RFP_watershed(~RFP_binarized) = 0;         % Added
mask = im2bw(RFP_watershed, 1);
overlay3 = imoverlay(RFP_adjust, mask, [1 .3 .3]);
figure, imshow(overlay3), title('Segmented cells');
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works, I understand the intent/logic, the syntax is a bit unfamiliar, but I can figure that out.

Comment: Followup Question - what is 'RFP_watershed(~RFP_binarized) = Inf;  ' doing? putting 'RFP_watershed(~RFP_binarized)' in the console creates a long column matrix...

Comment: @SoumitraBhoyar: Since `RFP_binarized` is a logical matrix (i.e. 0 and 1), you can use it to perform [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). Essentially, everywhere `~RFP_binarized` has a value of 1, a value of `Inf` will be placed in the corresponding spot in `RFP_watershed`. The `~` operator ("not" operator) is just flipping the zeroes and ones in `RFP_binarized`.

Answer (score 0):

There no magic bullet, but a few things you can try.

One is to filter the image with a very large circular disc, creating a blurry image that looks like the background. Then subtract it from the original image. That will tend to force the actual background to zero.

Another is to Otsu threshold to separate foreground from background. That creates a binary image. Then do a morphological open operation using a mask designed to look like the actual cells.

Comment: I'm afraid the first part of your answer does not work. The issue is not that there's insufficient contrast between background and foreground, but that when you use watershed, and create the inverted maxima, there doesn't seem to be a way for the program to distinguish between the inverted maxima ('minima') and the low background values.

Second point - well, there's no way to tell what the 'cells' look like - they're irregular clumps, NOT biological cells.